# Sortedset sublist printing

Tags: java, sortedset

Help me understand one thing.

I created a sub-list and print it. Now I can`t understand why "apple" is included to print, but "wind" is not. If I write "aa" it works how I want, but I want to use "apple" for creating sublist, where "apple" is not included. Is this real?

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.add("apple");
set.add("key");
set.add("value");
set.add("roof");
set.add("size");
set.add("wind");

System.out.println(set);
System.out.println(set.subSet("apple","wind"));
```

Output:

```
[apple, key, roof, size, value, wind]
[apple, key, roof, size, value]
```

Comment: That's how that method is working.[See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet(E,%20E)=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [documentation of `subSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet-E-E-)

> Parameters:
>
> - fromElement - low endpoint (inclusive) of the returned set
> - toElement - high endpoint (**exclusive**) of the returned set

So for `subSet("apple","wind")` `apple` is included in result, but `wind` is excluded.

If you want to be able to specify which endpoint should be included or excluded instead of `SortedSet` you can use `NavigableSet` as reference and its
[`subSet(E fromElement, boolean fromInclusive, E toElement, boolean toInclusive)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet-E-boolean-E-boolean-) method like

```
NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("apple", "key",
        "value", "roof", "size", "wind"));
System.out.println(set);
System.out.println(set.subSet("apple", false, "wind", false));
```

Output:

```
[apple, key, roof, size, value, wind]
[key, roof, size, value]
```